# How to add boot entry in systemd for android x86 in arch linux?

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, dual-boot, android

I have my kernal, ramdisk.img, initrd.img, system.img and data folder, all in one folder named android in my root directory, as mentioned in several tutorials on dual booting android x86 with linux. But the problem is that no one have mentioned how to boot it via systemd-boot, every guide is just for grub bootloader. How to I add boot entry in systemd for android x86 in arch linux?

Answer (score 0):

The files you mention need to be in your efi partition. Hopefully the following give you enough information to configure an entry for android.

The contents of my efi partition are as follows:

```
tree -L 1
.
├── EFI
├── gparted
├── initramfs-linux-fallback.img
├── initramfs-linux.img
├── initramfs-linux-lts-fallback.img
├── initramfs-linux-lts.img
├── intel-ucode.img
├── loader
├── System Volume Information
├── vmlinuz-linux
└── vmlinuz-linux-lts
```

This gives me the Arch linux mainline kernel and lts kernel plus an option to boot gparted live. The gparted directory contains an expanded image of the gparted live iso.

The loader directory contains:

```
.
├── entries
│   ├── arch.conf
│   ├── arch_lts.conf
│   ├── clonezilla.conf
│   └── gparted.conf
├── loader.conf
└── random-seed
```

Each .conf file in the entries directory gives you a new entry in your boot menu.

The arch.conf file contains:

```
title   Arch Linux
linux   /vmlinuz-linux
initrd  /intel-ucode.img
initrd  /initramfs-linux.img
options root=UUID=66f01fdf-82a1-4aef-a7f6-27b3ba7bb790 rw
```

Its basically a list of where the key components are.

The gparted.conf file contains:

```
title   GParted Live
linux   gparted/live/vmlinuz
initrd  gparted/live/initrd.img
options apm=power-off boot=live live-media-path=/gparted/live/ username=user noswap noeject  ip= net.ifnames=0
```

You need to move your android boot files to your efi partition and construct a .conf file in the entries folder. I think the rest of your android installation will need to be on its own partition

If you are interested the gparted conf file boots an extracted copy of the gparted live iso which is on the efi partition in the gparted directory. It uses the gparted initrd.img and vmlinuz which are located down the gparted directory tree.

Hope this leads you to a working solution. Note that the initrd.img and vmlinuz files have to be on the efi FAT partition which is "/" when the boot process starts

Good luck!